# How to get an element using CSS or Xpath by removing a specific text?

Tags: html, css, xpath, css-selectors

I need to get an element using CSS or XPath by searching by its text inside a list, each element contains the **Project Name**, the **Status** and the **Country** separated with the character `"|"`.

The problem is that I have to get an element by only using the **Project Name** and the **Country** as parameters and there is no way to edit the HTML.

```
<li>Project 1 | approved | USA</li>
<li>Project 2 | approved | China</li>
<li>Project 3 | disapproved | Russia</li>
```

What I need is to remove the **approved/disapproved** text from the query, something like

```
//li[contains(text(),'Project 1 USA')]
```

Is there a way to achieve this using CSS or Xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
//li[contains(text(),'Project 1') and contains(text(),'USA')]
```

...if you are able to separate the project name and location?